# Will IIS cache the file if the response header of that particular file has 'cache-control: private'?

Tags: iis, caching, http-headers, iis-7, cache-control

Since I'm unable to access the IIS, wanted to check the below point:
Will IIS cache the file, if the response header of that particular file has 'cache-control: private' ? (set at the code level)

cache-control: private indicates, that no proxy server (or shared cache points) shall cache the response. But need to know if main server caches the response (but it is a shared cache right ?)

***So, to summarize
If output cache is enabled on IIS (or not) and if we are setting 'cache-control: private' on code level (for that particular response), would that file be cached in IIS ?***

Comment: This link may help you: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/managing-performance-settings/configure-iis-7-output-caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/managing-performance-settings/configure-iis-7-output-caching).

Comment: thanks @samwu, I did go through it.. but it didn't give me the idea of whether or not the origin server will cache the response or not if cache-control is set to private.
Even in the definition of the cache-control: private, it states that "the response is cacheable only on the client and not by share (proxy server) caches.." But it doesn't mention if it includes origin server or not. :(

Comment: The origin server will cache the response if the cache-control is set to private, the cache-control:private is only related to Proxy caches only.

Comment: Thanks @samwu . But now i'm confused between `Private` and `ServerAndPrivate` under [HttpCacheability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcacheability?view=netframework-4.8#fields).

Comment: The two values are in the .net, I suggest you go test it yourself, because I also found this [Response.CacheControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms524721(v=vs.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).